# Ampersand is expanded when sharing Area 51 links via new Twitter

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, twitter

I committed to an Area 51 proposal ([Science Fiction](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction)) and clicked on the Twitter icon to share the link with both of my Twitter followers. Once Twitter figured out I was logged in, it redirected me behind the scenes, and by the time it settled I saw that the text Area 51 provided was truncated at the ampersand in "Q&A." In the address bar I could see that the `%26` in the Area 51 link had been expanded, somewhere along the line, to an ampersand.

Upon further experimentation this looks like a bug specific to "New Twitter" (which I had enabled in my Twitter account); when I reverted to "Twitter Classic" and clicked on the Area 51 proposal-sharing link again, I saw the full text in the box.

It may not be possible to fix this from Area 51, but I wasn't sure where else to mention it.

Comment: Probably should report to twitter.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out how to report this to Twitter; now its in their hands.

Comment: thanks for the assist, this bugged the hell out of me too :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this is a bug in New Twitter.

I "fixed" it on the se 2.0 side by changing

`Q&A`

to

`QnA`

very ghetto, but the bug is not ours, and this worked fine in Old Twitter. :P

Comment: It's "fixed" in Area 51 now too.